# Permissions model for Background Geolocation React/Ionic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ionic-framework, geolocation

How does React/Native ask for user permission to track user's geolocation in the background? Same for Ionic.

Also do any of these plugins remind/inform the user that their location has been tracked in background when they un-sleep their phone or bring the tracking app back into the foreground?

Comment: Yes, In Ionic users are prompted to ask location permission.

Comment: Yes, but does it stipulate that the tracking will persist when the phone is asleep and/or when the App is in the background? Is the user reminded when the phone wakes up and/or the App is brought back into the foreground?

Answer (score 0):

In iOS you have to add the tracking permissions to the .plist file. Also for iOS, an icon will display in the status bar to let the user know their location is being tracked. They have the ability to change this in their privacy settings.

Comment: Does anything additional/visual happen when the background is brought to the foreground or when the slleping phone is woken?

Comment: That depends on which option the user chooses or which you allow. The user can choose always allow, or only allow while using the app. So if they choose only allow while using the app, you will only have access to their location while their app is in the foreground.

Comment: So, please follow me here, if the user chooses "Always allow" then nothing, zilch, nada, is displayed apart from the initial permission request and the location icon on the status bar? Nothing?